# Best option to have a digital output in my desktop monitor?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, cable

I've kept on reading  a lot on this, but pretty much confused on what to go with. I'm having a desktop monitor which supports both `VGA` plus the `DVI`, but then my laptop has a `VGA` plus `HDMI`ports. What could be the best option in order to get a digital output?

1) Having a HDMI to VGA convertor

2) Having a HDMI to DVI cable

3) Having a VGA to DVI cable

Wanted to know the best option in terms of quality of display.

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Number 2 is the best because it's digital to digital. The other two are digital to analog (quality loss) and analog to digital.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is HDMI->DVI image sharper than VGA?](http://superuser.com/questions/899963/why-is-hdmi-dvi-image-sharper-than-vga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 is the best because it's digital to digital.

Keep in mind that HDMI supports transport of audio and HDCP encryption. DVI can`t.

The other two are digital to analog (quality loss) and analog to digital. Avoid A /D conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

Both the digital connections (HDMI and DVI) have MUCH better signal quality than analog VGA. Converting from analog to digital (or vice-versa) is always best avoided.
So you will need  to convert the HDMI output from the laptop to the DVI input on the monitor.
There are 2 options for that:
A cable with a HDMI connector on one end and a DVI on the other.
Or a HDMI-DVI converter plug in the laptop and a separate DVI-DVI cable.

In case you go for the 2nd option bear in mind that the conversion is best done as close to the output as possible. The converter plug needs a little electrical power which it will get from the laptop. If you would use a HDMI-HDMI cable and put the converter on the monitor side (another option in theory) it is possible the laptop can't supply enough power to the converter due to the cable and extra connectors in between. (Most laptops have fairly weak power-outputs anyway and many cheap cables are barely meeting the specs for resistance. The combination is often problematic, so best avoided.)

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I'm going with the HDMI-DVI cable.